# array push is not updated inside a loop in node js

Tags: node.js

trying push in array inside a loop

```
exports.bulkCartUpdate = async (req, res) => {
    
    let userId = req.params.userId;
    let CartId = req.profile.CartId;
    let items = req.body;

var promises = [];
      for( let i of items )
      {
         const productId = i.productId;
         const quantity = i.quantity;
         
          await Product.findById(productId).exec((err, productdet) => {
        
          let obj = {
            productId,
            quantity,
            price: productdet.price,
            name: productdet.name,
            stock: productdet.inventory
          }
         promises.push(obj);

        });
            console.log(promises);
      }
}
```

The above code is to get some details from api and make an object to push array .
but it shows empty.
Please help me , Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: `await` ONLY works when you `await` a promise.  Since you're passing a plain callback to `Product.findById().exec()`, it is likely NOT returning a promise and thus your plain callback gets called sometime LATER, after you're doing `console.log(promises)`.  So, the data has not yet been put in the array.  FYI, `promises` is completely the wrong variable name here as there are no promises involved in this code at all.  I don't know your database, but you need to use the interface that is actually promise-based.

Comment: will you please tell me what should i change , i updated the whole function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing `async - await` with callbacks, try to change your code like this:

```
exports.bulkCartUpdate = async (req, res) => {
    let userId = req.params.userId;
    let CartId = req.profile.CartId;
    let items = req.body;
  
    var promises = [];
    for (let i of items) {
      const productId = i.productId;
      const quantity = i.quantity;
  
      try {
        const product = await Product.findById(productId);
        if (product) {
          const obj = {
            productId,
            quantity,
            price: product.price,
            name: product.name,
            stock: product.inventory,
          };
          promises.push(obj);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Error fetching product with ID ${productId}`);
      }
    }
    console.log(promises);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an array of promises for `Promise.all()`. You need to remove callbacks and await and then push it into an array.

```
exports.bulkCartUpdate = async (req, res) => {

  let userId = req.params.userId;
  let CartId = req.profile.CartId;
  let items = req.body;

  var promises = [];
  for (let i of items) {
    const productId = i.productId;
    const quantity = i.quantity;
    promises.push(Product.findById(productId).lean());
  }

  Promise.all(promises).then(async (products) => {
    // console.log(products);
  }).catch(e => console.error(e))
}
```

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is the reference.

Comment: i can't push like this because i need some filds in product table and qunatity is from outside

Comment: You can add/update those fields after Promise.all()

Comment: where i use Promise.all ?

Comment: updated the code. please check